# Make Javascript execute strictly

Tags: javascript, browser, jslint

Currently, I'm trying to learn Javascript by writing my code in Gedit then attempting to execute it via Firefox.

However, web browsers tend to fail silently whenever it encounters an error in my code, and I can't quite shake the feeling that it's also ignoring other, more minor, problems in my code.  I'd really like to learn Javascript the right way, and not accidentally get in the habit of writing subtly wrong code.

**Is there a way to set up a web browser or run Javascript so it screams loudly at every error or mistake, no matter how minor?**

I looked into [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) -- are there any other ways of accomplishing this that I might have missed?

I also quickly (read: 5 minutes) looked at [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode) but I'm not sure if that's the same thing.

Comment: Have you looked at the firebug or chrome console?

Comment: You can set `javascript.options.strict` in `about:config` to `true`. I do not recommend it if you use FF 4+ because you'll see errors from extensions too.

Comment: BTW, use tripe equal (===) in your comparisons to check real equivalences; it makes it easier for detecting some errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the console in [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in order to view errors.  Chrome has its own built in console which can be used for the same purpose.  However, jslint is going to be much stricter than either console.

Comment: I didn't know that those existed, thanks.  Are they relatively straightforward to use, or are there any resources available on how to use them?

Comment: Very easy to use if you're just looking for errors.  Just load a page with the console tab open and any errors will be printed.  It can also be used as a Javascript REPL or a vardump.